# 'deviceorientation' not triggering in iOS browsers when referenced in iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iframe

I'm making a website running a "360 panorama viewer" in an iframe, where the source page uses JavaScript and `window.DeviceOrientationEvent` to determine if user is on a mobile device with orientation functionality. I'm seeing some strange behaviour on iOS Safari & Chrome:

> `window.DeviceOrientationEvent` evaluates to true, but `deviceorientation` event is never triggered.

This is not the case for Android Chrome - the event is triggered continuously as expected, when used in iFrame.

When accessing the page directly (on iOS) i see the event triggering. It is as if using it in an iframe "blocks" this event somehow.

It makes little sense to me, and researching it reveals little info, except some vague indications[1, 2] that it may actually have to do with the CORS - wether or not the iframe source is on the same root domain as the parent page. This makes even less sense to me..

Anyone have a clue?

[1](http://forums.tumult.com/t/control-gravity-device-tilt-not-working-ios-iframe/6307)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018114/ipad-orientation-info-gathered-from-a-child-object-like-iframe)

Comment: Is the iFrame on the same root domain as the parent page?

Comment: No - and that was the problem. The iframe content resided in an S3 bucket for static assets for the main webapp

Answer (score 6):

For anyone encountering this question now, it seems that Apple has disabled the `deviceorientation` API since iOS 12.2. Users now need to explicitly toggle it in `Settings > Safari > Motion and Orientation access`. See [here](https://github.com/w3c/deviceorientation/issues/57) for discussion.

Comment: does anyone know if there is a way to detect if this flag is false? the `DeviceMotionEvent` and `DeviceOrientatinonEvent` still eval to true

Comment: @JamesP if i'm following the Github thread linked from my answer the only way currently to do this is by [polling for the event itself](https://github.com/w3c/deviceorientation/issues/57#issuecomment-476390630).

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved using [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to pass information to the iframe. You need access to both websites however, the parent and the iframe. First listen to the `deviceorientation` event in the parent, then pass it into the iframe using `postMessage`.

```
// Parent
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function (event) {
let iframeElement = document.getElementById("my-iframe");
iframeElement.contentWindow.postMessage({
        alpha: event.alpha,
        beta: event.beta,
        gamma: event.gamma
    },
    "*"
);
// Child
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(event) {
    console.debug(event.data);
}
```

Comment: this is how 8th wall does it in their custom implementation, for example. It is possible, but it seems that may be more complex than just this.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone curious, I verified the problem to be CORS-related. It must be a security thing Apple does - blocking events on a page when used in `iframe`

My temp solution is to host files on same server, but its not scalable solution, so I think I'll have to set up some sort of proxy to deal with this.